# maximum concurrent client limit reached (65), please try again later

Tags: database, monetdb

I have been getting the following error in my application.

> maximum concurrent client limit reached (65), please try again later

I think I need to increase the limit for maximum concurrent clients. But I am not able to figure out how do I do that. Please help me out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should ask yourself whether you really need so many concurrent clients.  But if you really do, you could try raising the limit using the option `--set max_clients=<n>` where  is a number.
When using monetdb/monetdbd, you can set the `nclients` option for the database to do this (see the monetdb man page).